# Can I Adjust Thickness of bone "Stick"

Tags: bones

I'm going to animating and I thought "Stick" was perfect, so I chose this one.

But it's just a little thick, so it's too confusing with the mesh.

Can I adjust the thickness of this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe consider *B-Bone* instead of *Stick*, then you can adjust the size. Go to *Edit Mode* and with the bone(s) selected, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale the thickness. Instead of dragging the mouse you can also enter a small value like 0.01 to scale it down, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to set the scale.

Comment: After all, B-bone is more convenient than stick when customized. So I'll go with B-bone. Thank you.